# How do you reference new columns immediately after they are created in your SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do I need to write my SQL script to ensure my new column is visible on following lines after it is created.

This is the general form of my SQL:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

  if (not exists(select 1 from THIS_TABLE))
      BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE THIS_TABLE add THIS_COLUMN int
      END
COMMIT

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM THIS_TABLE
            WHERE THIS_COLUMN = 1))
    BEGIN
            UPDATE THIS_TABLE SET THIS_COLUMN = 1 
    END

COMMIT
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Invalid column name 'THIS_COLUMN'.
```

on this line:

```
        IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM THIS_TABLE
            WHERE THIS_COLUMN = 1))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The column has to be created before a query that uses it can be parsed.  You can accomplish this by putting the `update` in a different batch, using the "go" keyword:

```
alter table t1 add c1 int
go
update t1 set c1 = 1
```

Or by running the second transaction as dynamic SQL:

```
alter table t1 add c1 int
exec ('update t1 set c1 = 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

What Andomar said is correct, you need to use the `go` keyword.
However, the big problem is that your logic looks wrong. Let me go through each use case:

**If `THIS_TABLE` is not empty**

If the table is not empty, the `if` below returns `false` and you will never add the new column.

```
  if (not exists(select 1 from THIS_TABLE))
          BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE THIS_TABLE add THIS_COLUMN int
          END
```

Then, the next script obviously fails, because there is no such column `THIS_COLUMN`:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM THIS_TABLE
            WHERE THIS_COLUMN = 1))
```

**If `THIS_TABLE` is empty**

If the table is empty, the column is added:

```
  if (not exists(select 1 from THIS_TABLE))
          BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE THIS_TABLE add THIS_COLUMN int
          END
```

But then the next `if` will always be true and the update statement will affect zero rows (because table is empty).

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM THIS_TABLE
            WHERE THIS_COLUMN = 1))
BEGIN
        UPDATE THIS_TABLE SET THIS_COLUMN = 1 
END
```